# Calling C function from Objective-C loses passed in values

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, floating-point

I'm trying to keep a float[] of my table row heights. I found a nice class for doing so here: http://forums.macnn.com/t/224809/nsmutablearray-vs-a-plain-c-array-for-storing-floats.

The problem is that once the C function (located in another file) gets called, the float that I passed in becomes 0. This happens every single time, regardless of the float value.

C function:

```
typedef struct
{
    float *array;
    int count;
} floatArray;

BOOL AddFloatToArray ( floatArray *farray, float newFloat )
{
    if ( farray->count > 0 )
    {
        // The array is already allocated, just enlarge it by one
        farray->array = realloc ( farray->array, ((farray->count + 1) * sizeof (float)) );

        // If there was an error, return NO
        if (farray->array == NULL)
            return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        // Allocate new array with the capacity for one float
        farray->array = (float *)malloc ( sizeof (float) );

        // If there was an error, return NO
        if (farray->array == NULL)
            return NO;
    }
    printf("Adding float to array %f\n", newFloat);
    farray->array[farray->count] = newFloat;
    farray->count += 1;
    printArrayContents(farray);
    return YES;
}

int printArrayContents( floatArray* farray)
{
    printf("Printing array contents\n");
    for(int j=0; j < farray->count; j++)
        printf("%f\n", farray->array[j]);


    return 0;
}
```

Called from:

```
    NSDictionary* review = [self.reviews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    returnHeight = [ReviewCell cellHeightForReview:review];
    NSLog(@"Adding height to array: %0.0f", returnHeight);
    AddFloatToArray(heights, returnHeight);
```

Here's what gets logged:

```
2012-09-28 11:46:12.787 iOS-app[1605:c07] -[ProductDetailViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] [Line 598] Adding height to array: 101
Adding float to array 0.000000
Printing array contents
0.000000
2012-09-28 11:46:12.788 iOS-app[1605:c07] -[ProductDetailViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] [Line 598] Adding height to array: 138
Adding float to array 0.000000
Printing array contents
0.000000
0.000000
2012-09-28 11:46:12.788 iOS-app[1605:c07] -[ProductDetailViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] [Line 598] Adding height to array: 122
Adding float to array 0.000000
Printing array contents
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
2012-09-28 11:46:12.789 iOS-app[1605:c07] -[ProductDetailViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] [Line 598] Adding height to array: 139
Adding float to array 0.000000
Printing array contents
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

How can I ensure that the correct value is actually inserted into the float[]?

Comment: Tried the code exactly as you posted it and called using `CGFloat returnHeight = 120.f; AddFloatToArray(heights, returnHeight);` and works like a charm in my Xcode. Are you sure you didn't strip anything from your code when you c/p it here?

Comment: Everything's here. It's probably worth mentioning that the C functions are in a different file though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't declare the functions in the .h I was #importing. So everything compiled and ran, but the classes weren't communicating correctly. You'd think that would raise a warning or error.

Comment: It should have triggered a warning "Implicit declaration of function xxx is invalid in C99". Check that you have the `-Wimplicit-function-declaration` flag on.

Comment: That was not turned on, but I remember seeing that warning before. Google did not turn up this solution though. Thanks!

Comment: I also saw sometimes the "xxx undefined. assuming extern returning int" warning that could be related (not knowing the function signature, because you didn't import the headers, the compiler assumed the function returned an `int`, instead of a `float`, and the parameter stacking during the function call then messed up because of that). But I can't manage to reproduce this warning nor find the corresponding `-W` flag that would have helped in such case.